# relevent laravel query for postgres working query

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

I have the working working in postgres

```
select * from "prospects_audit_dump" where date_created::date between ['2021-03-01' and '2021-03-15'] and ( ("parent_id" in ('4747f33c-764c-11eb-b43f-0265ed7510c2', '771782c0-8197-11eb-8d62-020683bef092', '8c400d42-2470-11e9-917b-066c2def7d44') and "after_value_string" = 'MGL' and "before_value_string" != 'Open_inbound') or ("before_value_string" = 'Open_inbound' and "after_value_string" = 'MGL') or ("before_value_string" = 'MGL' and "after_value_string" = 'MQL'));
```

I have tried to convert this as laravel query

```
$audit_table_result=DB::table($type.'_audit_dump')->whereBetween(DB::raw('date_created::date'),['2021-03-01','2021-03-15');
  $audit_table_result=$audit_table_result->where(function ($query) use ($meeting_ids) {
    return $query->whereIn('parent_id', $meeting_ids)->where('after_value_string', 'MGL')->where('before_value_string', '!=', 'Open_inbound');
    }) ->orWhere(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('before_value_strings', 'Open_inbound')->where('after_value_string', 'MGL');
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('before_value_string', 'MGL')->where('after_value_string', 'MQL');
    });
   $audit_table_result=$audit_table_result->get();
```

but missing the outter bracket after `between '2021-03-01' and '2021-03-15' and`  select * from "prospects_audit_dump" where date_created::date between '2021-03-01' and '2021-03-15' and ( );
how to alter my laravel query.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here:

```
$audit_table_result=DB::table($type.'_audit_dump')->
whereBetween(DB::raw('date_created::date'),['2021-03-01','2021-03-15');
```

the parameters for [whereBetween](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) should be in array, you missed the close bracket, it should be:

```
$audit_table_result=DB::table($type.'_audit_dump')->
whereBetween(DB::raw('date_created::date'),['2021-03-01','2021-03-15']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following line of code:

```php
$audit_table_result=DB::table($type.'_audit_dump')->whereBetween(DB::raw('date_created::date'),['2021-03-01','2021-03-15');
```

with the following:

```php
$audit_table_result=DB::table($type.'_audit_dump')->whereBetween(DB::raw('date_created::date'),['2021-03-01','2021-03-15']); 
// you missed the closing square bracket `]`
```